# Placement of data table delete/edit button

Tags: buttons, data-tables, placement

Using material design and making a desktop application.

Should I add the delete and edit button on each row like this:

[image: 1]

or in the Color zone at the right (near the 3 dots):

[image: 2]

Answer (score 1):

Why not like this?
[image]

The ability to specific items is arguably better because of the shorter mouse movement and its easy to understand what's being edited.

But it depends, should a user be able to edit multiple items?

Comment: Hi, I edited this for clarity and removed the language about "preference". Objective answers shouldn't make reference to what you like or what you prefer. An option is either better or not, or it's at least possible to argue for it being better. Likes and preferences shouldn't be a factor.

Comment: Also, the type of clarifying question you ask at the end is the kind of thing that should be a comment under the main question. You can end up wasting your time by working on a question turns out to be based on a wrong assumption that you could have easily clarified first. Provide your answer when you have no further questions of your own.

Answer (score 0):

It depends!  ( I love giving that answer...not such a fan of receiving it. )

To expand.... as rhauger mentions above "should a user be able to edit multiple items?"  I like that question and would add another consideration.  How often is a user deleting rows?  Is deleting a primary action?  If so, the button should be promoted to the left side.  If it it is a seldom used action, then demote it to the end.  Same for "edit" functions.  Depending on the frequency of use...

This is based on the "Path To Completion: strategy from Nielsen Norman described here....

https://www.nngroup.com/articles/web-form-design/